# PHParray traversal

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, there is a function `wp_get_sidebars_widgets()` that spits out a multidimensional array of all registered sidebar ID's with their children active widget IDs.

For context, this is a sample output:

```
Array
(
[wp_inactive_widgets] => Array
    (
    )

[sidebar-requests] => Array
    (
        [0] => widget-demographics-4
        [1] => recent-posts-7
        [2] => widget-newsletter-11
    )

[sidebar-team] => Array
    (
        [0] => widget-sidebar-list-6
        [1] => widget-donate-2
    )

)
```

I am using this code inside of a widget to find the ID of the sidebar it lives in. For example, there can only be one 'widgets-newsletter-11', and it lives inside the 'sidebar-requests' widget area.

I am having trouble storing the ID of this widget area. Here is a simple version of the code I am trying to use.

```
$this_widget_id = 'widget-newsletter-11';
$this_widget_area_id;

$all_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();

foreach ( $all_widgets as $widget_area => $widget_id ) {
    if ( $widget_id == $this_widget_id )
        $this_widget_area_id = $widget_area;
}
```

At the end of this, the stored variable, `$this_widget_area_id` remains empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to add another loop inside your foreach. The array returned by `$wp_get_sidebars_widgets()` is 2 levels deep.  So as your code currently stands, you're comparing an array to your string "widget-newsletters-11"

Comment: Ah! Perfect! I added `foreach ( $widget_ids as $widget_order => $widget_id ) {
                if ( $widget_id == $this_widget_id )
                    $this_widget_area_id = $widget_area;
            }` and everything works fine

Comment: Before you go committing this code to prod, you should really rethink your approach.  wp_get_sidebars_widgets's is NOT meant for this use. 
 Read the docs: 
 https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_sidebars_widgets/

Answer (score 1):

I think you're checking an array against the Id, you should check whether that specific array contains the Id:

```
foreach ( $all_widgets as $widget_area => $widget_items ) {
    if ( in_array($this_widget_id, $widget_items, true) )
        $this_widget_area_id = $widget_area;
}
```

Hopefully I didn't misunderstand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to loop over the outer set of arrays.  You just want to loop over the sidebar-requests

```
$this_widget_id = 'widget-newsletter-11';
$this_widget_area_id;

$all_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
 $all_widgets = $all_widgets[sidebar-requests];
foreach ( $all_widgets as $widget_area => $widget_id ) {
    if ( $widget_id == $this_widget_id )
    $this_widget_area_id = $widget_area;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @eatpeanutbutter for recommending that I add another loop. I added

```
foreach ( $widget_ids as $widget_order => $widget_id ) {
    if ( $widget_id == $this_widget_id )
        $this_widget_area_id = $widget_area;
}
```

and everything works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, but this entire approach is a Bad Idea.  I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve with this piece of code, but using wp_get_sidebars_widgets() is almost certainly not the only way to accomplish it and it is certainly not the recommended way.  wp_get_sidebars_widgets() is marked as private and is not intended to be used by theme and plugin developers.

Comment: Good catch. I wasn't really expecting any WP specific support here, as I knew it was just a stupid PHP error I had, but good catch nonetheless. I'll look into some other options for achieving the same result, without using a private WP function.